# gem react on rails: webpack.config.js

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5, webpack-2, react-on-rails

I use Rails 5.1 and the react_on_rails gem v10.0.2

I want to use css modules and css-loader and I'm wondering where to put the webpack.config.js - File?

As I see it the current version of the react_on_rails gem doesn't have the client directory (where the webpack.config.js file used to be stored) anymore.

The react components are stored in /app/javascripts.

Answer (score 2):

I met the similar problem, and I found out there is no such thing called `webpack.config.js` in rails webpack. Instead, they manage their configurations in the `config/webpack/*.js` files.

More details can be found in the link: [rails-webpack-config](https://github.com/rails/webpacker/blob/master/docs/webpack.md)